# MATLAB: sym function does not works

Tags: matlab

In matlab I want to create symbolic vector:

```
X = sym(['x_n' 'x_(n-1)' 'x(n-2)'])
```

however, I get

```
??? Error using ==> sym.sym>expression2ref at 2408
Error: Unexpected 'identifier' [line 1, col 11]

Error in ==> sym.sym>char2ref at 2378
    s = expression2ref(x);

Error in ==> sym.sym>tomupad at 2147
        S = char2ref(x);

Error in ==> sym.sym>sym.sym at 102
                S.s = tomupad(x,'');
```

if I try create, e.g. just `X = sym(['x_n' 'x_(n-1)'])`, it's ok, so what's wrong?

Comment: The fact that X = sym(['x_n' 'x_(n-1)']) worked didn't mean you created a vector... you created a nicely long symbolic variable X =x_nx_(n - 1)

Comment: @natan Could you perhaps expand your comment by stating how a vector could be created and post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a symbolic vector (or matrix) you just need one set of quotes around the square brackets:

```
X = sym('[x_(n) x_(n-1) x_(n-2)]')
```

Or

```
X = sym('[x_(n);x_(n-1);x_(n-2)]')
```

I'm assuming that you had typos in the first and third element of the vector and desire to define `x_` as a function of `n` (if not, see below). However, this often isn't the most flexible way of building symbolic arrays. I'd use the `syms` function instead of `sym` and avoid building strings (though sometimes creating large vector/matrix equations systematically with strings can be easier):

```
syms x_(n)
X = [x_(n) x_(n-1) x_(n-2)]
```

Lastly, as the help for `sym` indicates, one can also automatically create vectors and matrices of enumerated variables, e.g.:

```
X = sym('x_',[1 3])
```

If you don't actually want to specify a vector of functions, then this option is very convenient.